# Firebase app invite crashing on swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-invites

I've added firebase app invites in my swift based iOS application. I have followed [this complete instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/ios?hl=el) however, it has been crashing on `invite.open()` line while showing invite dialog.

The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>
> reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: GINInviteResources.bundle)'.

Did anyone managed to make it work?

Comment: Links can stop working, please post the relevant code in the question as formatted text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging for 2 days what I found was FirebaseInvites.framework seems to have resource dependancies for GINInviteResources.bundle and GPPACLPickerResources.bundle.

Somehow, pod was not including it in to my project.(Still could not find why) but adding this two dependencies manually in to my target worked like a charm.

PS: Adding this answer to save someone's effort.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I too faced this.
Download `framework SDK zip` from https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup and get those bundles from `\Invites\Resources\..`